# Get all the values from connected nodes grouped by keys

Tags: gremlin

I follow the kelvinlawrence tutorial, and I am trying to get **all** the attribute values from connected nodes grouped by the attribute keys.

The following query is almost what I need, but it wraps the elements in additional arrays. Mind that, for the purpose of short resultset I fill in valueMap params.

```
g.V().limit(2).out("route").valueMap("country", "code").unfold().dedup().group().by(keys).by(values)

=>[country:[[PK]],code:[[SKZ],[KHI],[ISB]]]
```

What I need is:

```
[country:[PK],code:[SKZ,KHI,ISB]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every property on a vertex saves inside an array, you should first take the values out by `unfold()` them. and then `fold()` it into one array.

```
g.V().limit(2).out("route").valueMap("country", "code")
.unfold().dedup()
.group()
.by(keys)
.by(select(values).unfold().fold())
```